# sync failed during the starting of the android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

normally when I start android studio then there is a problem in the .xml to execute when I try to update plugins then "some conflicts are occurred during installation" this message is received on the screen .

please help me out...

I have tried a new gradle 5.1 version at the place of old gradle which was gradle 4.1

Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;

Comment: Does you gradle file itself have issues? Could you post your gradle file and the xml file that this error is referencing?